# How do i merge these two database tables into a single result set?

Tags: sql, view

I have two tables in the system. I'm trying to make a VIEW that represents them both together, and i'm not sure how this can be done or even IF this can be done.

#### Pets

```
PetId INT PK
Name  VARCHAR(100)
```

#### PetOtherNames

```
PetID INT PK FK
Name VARCHAR(100) PK
```

So, i have a table of pets. The name (in this table) is their formal common name. Each pet maybe have Zero-To-Many other names. These names are never displayed BUT are to be used in a search query.

So, lets look at some data.

#### Pets Data

```
1. Fred
2. Barney
3. Foo
4. Megan Fox (boom tish)
```

#### PetsOtherName Data

```
2. B-b-b-Barney
2. Bannana Barney
2. Banannarama
4. TapTap
```

So ... if i make a VIEW of these two tables, i expect the following results....

```
SELECT *
FROM PetsView
ORDER BY PetId, Name

1. Fred
2. B-b-b-Barney
2. Barney
2. Bannana Barney
2. Banannarama
3. Foo
4. Megan Fox
4. TapTap
```

And this will then enable me to do the following ....

```
SELECT PetId, Name
FROM PetsView
WHERE CONTAINS(Name, 'Fox')
```

... and returns 4. Fox

```
SELECT PetId, Name
FROM PetsView
WHERE CONTAINS(Name, 'Fox')
```

... and returns 4. TapTap

cheers :)

PS. I'm not sure i worded the title of this post, so please feel free to edit it appropriately (or suggest a better title, for me to update).

Update: This is for sql2008, but i'm assuming the result would be tsql .. so it should/could apply accross the board.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a view that creates a UNION of the two tables:

```
CREATE VIEW PetsView AS
SELECT * FROM Pets
UNION
SELECT * FROM PetOtherNames
```

Comment: Try to select the columns explicitly. Most probably your tables doesn't have the same columns.

Comment: Yeah. i needed to do that too. once i did that, it was all good :)

Answer (score 4):

Not to steal any thunder, but I've been bitten by not using UNION ALL before.

Basically, if you have the same exact petId-Name combination in either table, only one record will appear in the result set if you just use UNION.  By using UNION ALL, you will see the duplicates (which you may or may not want).

```
CREATE VIEW PetsView AS
SELECT petId, [Name] FROM Pets
UNION ALL
SELECT petId, [Name] FROM PetOtherNames
```

(In SQL Server, "name" is a keyword, so I used the escaping bracket)

Comment: I think "name" is a keyword in SQL Server. Try this:

CREATE VIEW PetsView AS
SELECT petId, [Name] FROM Pets
UNION ALL
SELECT petId, [Name] FROM PetOtherNames

Comment: cheers, but i'm sure i want UNION, not UNION ALL. If the ID + Name appears in both tables, then i only need it to be listed ONCE. Hopefully, it would exist in both ... :) (can i make a unique key constraint?)

Comment: (Update) I had different fields in either table, which is why it originally didn't work. I listed the fields that do exist, and it works. (i also removed my previous comment about it not working).

Comment: Good! Use UNION, which will effectively always give you unique results.